# Kate not showing all files in Filesystem Browser

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, kate

I have a fresh install of Kate on Ubuntu 20.04. The Filesystem Browser in tree view only shows files in a directory if the directory also has subdirectories. See image for an example:

[image]

The directory "constant" has a subdirectory ("polyMesh"), so  both the subdir and the file ("transportProperties") are shown. However, the directory "system" also has files but no subdirectories, so the files are not shown. I can see the missing files if I go into the "system" subdir (i.e. set it as the root tree item), but I don't want to do that; I want to see the whole directory tree in one view.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? The currently behavior is super annoying.

Comment: As a band-aid fix, you can create a dummy folder in the folders that are not showing correctly, but this is a real hack. It seems that the problem is not with Kate or the File System Browser plugin at all, but is a bug in KDE's KDirOperator class, that the Kate plugin uses. I'm going to report the bug, and probably make my own File System plugin that uses some of Qt's native file system tools.

Comment: I upgraded to Fedora 33 (for other reasons) and the issue is solved.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the KDE package for that distribution fixes the bug in `KDirOperator`.